# Using left join is null instead of where not exists in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot change my code to left join is null while I am trying use where in table2. Please see my query bellow

```
      SELECT  table1.column1,  table1.column2
      FROM table1
          WHERE NOT 
              EXISTS (
                    SELECT table2.column1, table2.column2
                    FROM table2
                    WHERE table2.column1= table1.column1
                    AND table2.location_id= 6
                )
      GROUP BY Barcode
```

Can you please explain even it's not useful or bad question. It is my real problem.

Comment: Read.. [Second Link in google Search for 'sql left join not null'](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Comment: *"I know that left join is null performance is better than where not exists"* Can you explain why you think that is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use left join?

```
SELECT  table1.column1,  table1.column2
   FROM table1
   LEFT JOIN table2
   ON table2.column1= table1.column1
     AND table2.location_id= 6
   WHERE table2.column1 is null
   GROUP By Barcode
```

Also, your assumption that left join is better is not necesarrily correct. The article linked by TsSkTo in the comments to your question shows that left join is a worse solution for MSSQL